# How do I use a custom Plural-Forms in django.po?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, gettext

I want to use a custom Plural-Forms scheme in my django.po for Russian, but when I change it, it does not affect the results of ungettext.

I’ve found out that if I use the same translation file without Django, Plural-Forms works correctly.

Here is the django.po file.

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-09-18 01:26+0000\n"
"Language: ru\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=4; plural=(n==1 ? 0 : n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 1 : n"
"%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 2 : 3)\n"

#: testapp/test.py:5
#, python-format
msgid "One new notification."
msgid_plural "%(count)s new notifications."
msgstr[0] "Одно новое оповещение."
msgstr[1] "%(count)s новое оповещение."
msgstr[2] "%(count)s новых оповещения."
msgstr[3] "%(count)s новых оповещений."
```

If I run this

```
import gettext

filename = "testp/conf/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo"
trans = gettext.GNUTranslations(open( filename, "rb" ) )
trans.install()

def translated_message(notifications_count):
    return trans.ungettext(
        "One new notification.",
        "%(count)s new notifications.",
        notifications_count
    ) % {"count": notifications_count}

print translated_message(1)
print translated_message(2)
print translated_message(5)
print translated_message(51)
```

The following is printed:

```
Одно новое оповещение.
2 новых оповещения.
5 новых оповещений.
51 новое оповещение.
```

And this is exactly what I expect to be the result of ungettext.

But the output is different when the same compiled translation file (django.mo) is used in a Django project.

With django.utils.translation.ungettext it changes to this:

```
Одно новое оповещение.
2 новое оповещение.
5 новых оповещения.
Одно новое оповещение.
```

It obviously means that in this case the forms (msgstr) are read correctly, but Plural-Forms is ignored (i.e. the regular scheme for Russian language is used instead of what I have defined).

Answer (score 1):

All catalogs are merged in Django, so the task described in the question cannot be accomplished at the moment.

Probably, the cleanest solution could be to just use gettext directly.

Also refer to [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23520).